# Is bin a keyword?

Tags: python, keyword

Just a quick question: Is 'bin' a keyword in Python? It didn't show up on the keywords lists I found on Google. But when I try to name a variable bin, it shows up in purple.

Thanks

Comment: It's a built-in function (you don't need to import it) https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Comment: ... which means that, unlike keywords, you can reassign it - but you shouldn't.

Answer (score 4):

Iain is quite right, `bin` is a built in function. Different syntax highlighters might show that differently; some only have the category of keywords, and then the highlighter author has to choose between not highlighting builtins or showing them the same as keywords. The [Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) lists the actual keywords, while the [library reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html) lists built-in functions, constants and types, which can be shadowed by names stored in your own name spaces. Doing so is usually regarded as poor form, e.g. if you name a variable `list`, it would be harder to reference the [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) type, a reader might think you did when you were accessing your variable, and it doesn't say what the variable is for (list of what).

Answer (score 0):

`bin` is a builtin function. In the default color scheme in IDLE, builtins are purple #900090, and keywords are orange #ff7700.